# How to read values from from a text file with columns?

Tags: python, slice

I'm trying to read data from a file that is separated in columns with data from each year and lines with the name of the values (eg:number of times I opened Firefox on the year 2015). Now, I know how to read a specific line but I'm having trouble reading from the different columns. They are 10 spaces wide but only have values like -0.5 and 1.2, so it doesn't get to the tenths and only 1 decimal. Like this:

```
-3.5         1.0        -2.9         6.8
```

How would I do it to read these values since I have to compare them as floats to other data? Would I slice it? If so I haven't found a way to do so.

Comment: `data = [float(cell) for cell in line.split()]` may help.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many columns you are going to have you can split the whitespace and coerce to a float:

```
[float(i) for i in "-3.5         1.0        -2.9         6.8".split()]
```

Yields:

```
[-3.5, 1.0, -2.9, 6.8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've got your line in a string, the simplest would be to split the string on the whitespace.

```
values = line.split()
```

The iterate through that list and cast to a float.

```
float_values = [float(v) for v in values]
```

Comment: Thanks! So out of curiosity, is there a way of doing it with indexing or by slicing it? Someone told me there was a way to do it without .split() but I can't seem to find a "pretty" way to do it. I'll use this but just curious.

Comment: "split" is your friend. Problem here is you would need to know the character length of the value.